# Error While Trying to Update to Windows 10 Fall Creators Update 1709

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade, windows-10-v1703, windows-10-v1709

I have tried to install the Fall Creators Update 1709 for 25 odd times and each time it restarts multiple times before restoring to previous version and restarting Windows without the new update. When I checked the update history, it says "Requires a restart to finish installing". Restarting then does nothing.

I am running Windows 10 Home Version 1703 currently.

I have Googled the issue and tried the following:

- Removing all USB devices except mouse and keyboard
- Removing Avira Antivirus, both malware removal tools and turning off
  Windows defender
- Updating the BIOS (Asus Prime z272M-PLUS)
- Installing Asus AI Suite 3
- Using the Windows Update Tool (I think)

I'm sure there is more but I have been trying to update for 3 weeks so I forgot some of the things I have tried.

Somewhere I think I found an error saying `Error 0xc1900101 - 0x30017 FIRST_BOOT` but I'm not sure how I found that.

Is anyone able to help me at all?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/upgrade/resolve-windows-10-upgrade-errors#the-windows-10-upgrade-process

Comment: There should be a log generated with more details then a generic error

Comment: That might have been where I got the second error from but just in case, can you let me know where to get the log?

Comment: The event viewer has no recent errors. Certainly none related to the update

Comment: Install from an external device, e.g. USB flash drive.

Comment: The failure is within WinPE, event viewer, won’t have any information on the reason it’s failing at the stage which it’s failing at

Comment: 0x30017 = ERROR_CRC so check your HDD for issues.

Comment: So, at this point, why not just do a clean install...?

Answer (score 0):

It could be a HDD problem. 
Try to repair the system drive. 
The system drive is the drive that contains the system partition. 
This is usually the C: drive.

To check and repair errors on the system drive:

- Click Start.
- Type `command`.
- Right-click "Command Prompt" and then left-click "Run as administrator".
- If you are prompted by UAC, click Yes. 
  If it asks for an administrator password, enter one.
- Type `chkdsk /F` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- When you are prompted to schedule a check the next time the system restarts, type `Y`.

You may find more information at [Resolve Windows 10 upgrade errors](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/upgrade/resolve-windows-10-upgrade-errors#the-windows-10-upgrade-process).